# Set active class on column in component which iterates within a component render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Simply put, I would like to toggle active class on render function of component, which is iterating through a dataset (columns). My code does add class active to each column but it alls it to all columns instead of just one.

Any help would be great!

```
import React from "react";


import Utils from "#/utils/Utils";
import SVGInline from "react-svg-inline";
import {houseSvg, businessSvg, eventsSvg, petsSvg, healthSvg, webDesignSvg, creativeSvg} from '#/utils/Svg';

import sass from './categoriesiconslist.scss';
import CategoriesManager from "#/ui/categories/CategoriesManager";

export default class CategoriesIconsList extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        layout: "horizontal",
        className: null,
        containerFluid: true,
        styles: {},
        enableColClick: false,
        colClick: () => {}
    };

    state = {
        activeCol: false
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
    };

    onColClick(e, component, data) {
        e.preventDefault();


        component.setState({
            activeCol: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section class={`categories-list-icons ${this.props.layout} ${this.props.className ? this.props.className : '' }`} style={this.props.styles}>
                {this.props.title ? 
                    <div class="base-title">
                        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
                    </div> : ''
                }
                <div class={
                    `   ${this.props.containerFluid ? "container-fluid" : "container"} 
                        ${this.props.layout == "horizontal" ?  "seven-cols" : "single-col"} 
                    `} >
                    {   
                        Object.keys(CategoriesManager.CATEGORIES_LIST).map((value, idx) => {
                            var data = CategoriesManager.CATEGORIES_LIST[value];

                            return (
                                <div 
                                    class={"col " + (this.props.layout == "horizontal" ? "col-sm-1 " : " ") + (this.state.activeCol ? 'active ' : ' ')} 
                                    onClick={ this.props.enableColClick ? (e) => { this.onColClick(e, this, data) } : '' } 
                                    key={idx}
                                >
                                        {data.icon}
                                    <div class="txt">{data.title}</div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the `activeCol` state as a boolean up top and every column is reading from that state, so they are all either active or not. Try creating a column component and inside each, they can maintain their own `activeCol` state.